# DefectDojo default username and password

Tags: passwords

I have installed a DEV instance of defectdojo, and I need to find the default login and password. During installation it states:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  WARNNING: Dev install has hard coded credentials - you have been warned.  !
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

but it doesn't give the login credentials, only the credentials for the database it created.
If I go into the database, the only thing I can find is this:

```
mysql> select * from dojo_cred_user;
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

The official installation [guide](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/defectdojo/stable/defectdojo.pdf) states that it is user:admin password:administrator But this does not work.

What is the default password and username?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't remember the admin password, you can create a new superuser with:

```
$ docker-compose exec uwsgi /bin/bash -c 'python manage.py createsuperuser'
```

Answer (score 0):

From: https://github.com/DefectDojo/django-DefectDojo/blob/master/DOCKER.md

Access the application
Navigate to http://localhost:8080 where you can log in with username admin. To find out the admin password, check the very beginning of the console output of the initializer container, typically name 'django-defectdojo_initializer_1', or run the following:

```
container_id=(`docker ps -a \
--filter "name=django-defectdojo_initializer_1" \
| awk 'FNR == 2 {print $1}'`) && \
docker logs $container_id 2>&1 | grep "Admin password:"
```

or:

`docker logs django-defectdojo_initializer_1`

Make sure you write down the first password generated as you'll need it when re-starting the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this command from the official docker docs, [link](https://github.com/DefectDojo/django-DefectDojo/blob/master/DOCKER.md):

```
$ docker-compose logs initializer | grep "Admin password:"
initializer_1   | Admin password: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```